Invoking base class operator results in WARN (bpy.rna): unable to get Python class for RNA struct
I'm currently developing an addon and encountered a nasty issue with operator inheritance. I have a base class operator and needed to create a subclass that extends this functionality with a minor override. Despite my efforts to resolve it, I’ve found that executing the base operator triggers a warning. Below is a simple reproducible code sample that illustrates the problem:
import bpy

class WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.base_class_operator"
    bl_label = "Base Class Operator"
    bl_description = "Base Class Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Base Executed")
        return {'FINISHED'}


class WEB_OT_SubclassOperator(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator):
    bl_idname = "web.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Subclass Operator"
    bl_description = "Subclass Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Subclass Executed")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

I get the following warning:

WARN (bpy.rna):
C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v420\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.cc:8655
bpy_class_call: unable to get Python class for RNA struct
'TEST_OT_base_class_operator'

I need both operators. What am I doing wrong?

Hi, change the register order can resolve the issue, see the post below.

I don't know the exact technical reason this happens, but whenever I need two operators to inherit functionality, I just create a normal Python class to act as a mixin and put the shared functionality there. Make sure you put the mixin class before bpy.types.Operator in the Operator class declaration. That seems to work for me."
import bpy


class BaseOperator:
    op_type: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    def exec_operator(self, context):
        self.report({"INFO"}, f"Executing {self.op_type}")
        

class WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator(BaseOperator, bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.base_class_operator"
    bl_label = "Base Class Operator"
    bl_description = "Base Class Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        self.exec_operator(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class WEB_OT_SubclassOperator(BaseOperator, bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "web.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Subclass Operator"
    bl_description = "Subclass Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}
    
    

    def execute(self, context):
        self.exec_operator(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.web.some_operator(op_type="Child")
    bpy.ops.test.base_class_operator(op_type="Parent")


Hello, thank you for your answer. Yes, that is my current workaround—using a common base class—so I end up with three classes. However, I was wondering about the technical details. In my opinion, this should definitely be considered a bug, as normal object-oriented programming should have worked with my original approach.

I guess mixins are the way to go like in your example.

Yeah, I feel like I also had this problem a long time ago and found some random answer on a forum post from 9 years ago but I can't remember the reason why it does this.

Change the register order to resolve the problem
register the subclass first
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)


Or copy the base class
import bpy

class WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "test.base_class_operator"
    bl_label = "Base Class Operator"
    bl_description = "Base Class Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Base Executed")
        return {'FINISHED'}

# copy base class
class Base(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator):
    pass

class WEB_OT_SubclassOperator(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator):
    bl_idname = "web.some_operator"
    bl_label = "Subclass Operator"
    bl_description = "Subclass Operator Description"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Subclass Executed")
        return {'FINISHED'}



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Base)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WEB_OT_SubclassOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Base)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WEB_OT_BaseClassOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thank you for your answer. That's interesting because I thought I did try that. It also doesn't make any sense that registering the derived class ahead of its base class works. Yet it does work. Some really spooky things going on! But I think as Jakemoyo has mentioned, mixins it probably the proper approach. Do you think so too? I'm still really interested in the technical details of this weird behavior though.

It seems that need to study the source code of Blender to know why. I guess: When you register the base class first, the content of the base class changes, and then you register the inherited subclasses that have been registered by the base class, which will conflict.
In most cases Blender does not support internal class inheritance.
